# Command Line for Enable Dragging

Tags: macos, command-line, trackpad

In MacOS, in the Accessibility widget (in System Preferences) if you scroll all the way down to 'Mouse & Trackpad', and then click on the 'Trackpad Options' button, there is a by-default-unchecked box for 'Enable Dragging'.  This option is what allows you to "tap and drag" a window around using its titlebar.

I need to know the command line for checking that box.  Can anyone help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The easy way to find the plist key for a given preference is to open a Finder window of ~/Library/Preferences, set it to List View, sorted by Date Modified.

Then, set the preference and see what file gets modified.

From that, I get two almost identical files modified (on 10.14.5):

```
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist
com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad.plist
```

They contain the following relevant keys:

```
<key>DragLock</key>
<false/>
<key>Dragging</key>
<false/>
<key>TrackpadThreeFingerDrag</key>
<false/>
```

so you can set these keys directly with `defaults`:

```
defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad Dragging -bool true
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad Dragging -bool true
```

You can include three-finger dragging or Drag Lock, if that's what you want with similar commands.

Finally, run the following for the writes to take effect:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemAdministration.framework/Resources/activateSettings -u
```

Comment: Didn't work for me on Mojave.

Comment: @sepehr Which bit? Which files were modified when you changed the prefs? Did the plists contain any relevant keys?

Comment: Setting the keys directly with `defaults`. I haven't yet checked the plists to be honest.

Comment: Adding to this: According to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/414836/130792), you can make `defaults write` take effect without logout-login/restarting with `activateSettings -u`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `-int` type instead of `-bool`, so, the commands should be:

```
defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad Dragging -int 1
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad Dragging -int 1
```

---

Unfortunately the `defaults` *command* does not necessarily tell one the correct *type* the *key* is and one can easily mistake a `0` or `1` as a *boolean* instead of an *integer*, or visa versa, when using the, e.g., `defaults read ...` *command*.

Using **PlistBuddy**, as in the output below, one can see the target *keys* are *integer*, not *boolean*.

```
% /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -x -c 'print :Dragging' ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<integer>0</integer>
</plist>
% 
% 
% /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -x -c 'print :Dragging' ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<integer>0</integer>
</plist>
%
```

---

Note that in reading these two files with **PlistBuddy**, they are original and untouched having never been manually edited previously and therefore what's reported in the *output* is the proper *type* for the *keys*.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: @nohillside, Having just checked the _value_ of the mentioned _keys_ in both of the mentioned **PLIST** _files_, using **Xcode**, the mentioned _keys_ are defined as **Number**, _not_ **Boolean**, so using `-int` is actually the correct and proper way to modify these _keys_.

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks. When converted to XML they show up as TRUE and FLALSE. Interesting.

Comment: @nohillside, Also, using `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` they show as: `<integer>0</integer>`

Comment: You can also find the type of a field by using `defaults export <domain> - > tmp` and check `tmp` to see the type