# How can I enable keyboard shortcut preference after modifying it through `defaults write com.apple.symbolichotkeys AppleSymbolicHotKeys`?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, defaults

I modify keyboard shortcut by defaults command.

For example,

```
# Disable "Search word in terminal man page index"
defaults write com.apple.symbolichotkeys AppleSymbolicHotKeys -dict-add 124 "<dict><key>enabled</key><false/><key>value</key><dict><key>parameters</key><array><integer>65535</integer><integer>26</integer><integer>262144</integer></array><key>type</key><string>standard</string></dict></dict>"

# Change "Move focus to next window" shortcut to Alt + Tab
defaults write com.apple.symbolichotkeys AppleSymbolicHotKeys -dict-add 27 "<dict><key>enabled</key><true/><key>value</key><dict><key>parameters</key><array><integer>65535</integer><integer>48</integer><integer>524288</integer></array><key>type</key><string>standard</string></dict></dict>"
```

How can I enable to work them without restart OS?

I expect there are some Input Service and need to restart it.

ex. `killall SomeInputService`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On macos Big Sur `11.2.1` I have been able to resolve this problem. This solution applies to `com.apple.symbolichotkeys` plist for OS wide shortcuts as well as trackpad related plists.

After running the `default write ...` commands, run the following command.

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemAdministration.framework/Resources/activateSettings -u
```

From my experience, it will read the plists and force them to take effect.

You may need to ensure the `System Preferences` app is not running before you run the command.

Some log output will be available if you run this before:

```
defaults write com.apple.activatesettings log true
```

However there is no output about parsing the `com.apple.symbolichotkeys` plist although it seems to read that plist.

Answer (score 1):

On 12.1, I wasn't able to solve the issue with the accepted solution by itself, but by adding an additional step to ensure a `defaults read` on the plist prior to running `activateSettings`, things now correctly apply the new settings. I verified a few times that this additional step makes the difference and have a hunch that this step is lazily updating an in-memory cache of the plist file.

Example Usage:

```
# Disable Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Mission Control -> Move left/right a space.
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :AppleSymbolicHotKeys:79:enabled false" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :AppleSymbolicHotKeys:80:enabled false" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :AppleSymbolicHotKeys:81:enabled false" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :AppleSymbolicHotKeys:82:enabled false" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist

# Ask the system to read the hotkey plist file and ignore the output. Likely updates an in-memory cache with the new plist values.
defaults read com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist > /dev/null

# Run reactivateSettings to apply the updated settings.
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemAdministration.framework/Resources/activateSettings -u
```